# Give support for validation on optional parameter using class-validator in NestJS and GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, nest, nestjs, class-validator

I have this `input` for updating the block. I want users can update name or content or both.
Now problem is if I pass only name GrapQL throw an Error like **`Variable \"$updateBlockInput\" got invalid value { name: \"Updated again\" }; Field content of required type String! was not provided.`** and vice varsa.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**update-block.input.ts**

```
import { InputType, Field } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { IsOptional, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

@InputType()
export class UpdateBlockInput {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Field()
  name?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Field()
  content?: string;
}
```

**block.resolver.ts**

```
...
@Mutation(returns => BlockType)
updateBlock(
  @Args('id') id: string,
  @Args('updateBlockInput') updateBlockInput: UpdateBlockInput,
) {
  return this.blockService.update(id, updateBlockInput);
}
...
```

**Mutation**

```
mutation(
  $id: String!
  $updateBlockInput: UpdateBlockInput!
) {
  updateBlock(
    id: $id
    updateBlockInput: $updateBlockInput
  ) {
    name
    content
  }
}
```

**Variables**

```
{
  "id": "087e7c12-b48f-4ac4-ae76-1b9a96bbcbdc",
  "updateBlockInput": {
    "name": "Updated again"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if they are optional then you need to avoid `IsNotEmpty` and replace is with `IsString` to say that if the value is present it has to be string type only.

If you want to accept either and fail when non were sent you need to write an own custom validator because this case isn't supported out of the box.

an example:

```js
import {ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface} from 'class-validator';
@ValidatorConstraint({async: false})
export class IsInPast implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    public validate(value: unknown): boolean {
        if (typeof value !== 'string' && typeof value !== 'number') {
            return false;
        }
        const now = new Date();
        now.setHours(23);
        now.setMinutes(59);
        now.setSeconds(59);
        now.setMilliseconds(999);
        return `${value}`.match(/^\d+$/) !== null && `${value}` <= `${now.getTime()}`;
    }

    public defaultMessage(): string {
        return 'Should be in past';
    }
}
```

and later somewhere in the code:

```js
@Validate(IsInPast)
public dateField: string;
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of a custom validator?  Thanks.

Comment: added to the answer.